# Lost date while converting/parsing String to Datetime Java

Tags: java, parsing, jodatime

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter1 =
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

String timestamp = "2021-02-03 23:22:23 +0000 UTC";

DateTime converted1 = dateFormatter1.parseDateTime(timestamp);

Invalid format: "2021-02-03 23:22:23 +0000 UTC" is malformed at " 23:22:23 +0000 UTC"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2021-02-03 23:22:23 +0000 UTC" is malformed at " 23:22:23 +0000 UTC"
```

Getting an exception while parsing String to Datetime Java, can anyone please help?

Tried various formats like:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z').withZone(UTC)
```

Comment: I've searched a lot of StackOverflow posts but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Are you using the Joda-Time library? If yes, please edit the question and say so, e.g. by tagging `jodatime`. Why are you using Joda-Time instead of the Java 8 Time API?

Comment: Why do you believe that input string `2021-02-03 23:22:23 +0000 UTC` would parse with pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`. They are not even close to match. To begin with, the pattern specifies there must be a `T` between the date part and the time part, but the input has a space. I highly recommend you **read the documentation** on how the pattern works, before you blindly try some other random pattern.

Comment: @Andreas Yes I'm using `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat`. The inputs are fixed, the format is not up to me. I'm trying to get a DateTime object from the string. So given that the input string is immutable, how can I convert strings in that kind of format to DateTime object?

Comment: The input format may not be up to you, but the format *pattern* is, so you read the [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) and learn how the pattern works (e.g. what `'T'` means and why it doesn't apply to your case), so you can make a better attempt, rather than just grabbing a pattern off the web, and asking us to write your code for you. --- That 5th variant in the question with the `.withZone(UTC)` is just so horrendously wrong, it proves without a doubt that you never bothered to read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is not correct. Use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z z`

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String timestamp = "2021-02-03 23:22:23 +0000 UTC";
        DateTimeFormatter fmtInput = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z z");

        DateTime dtSource = fmtInput.parseDateTime(timestamp);
        System.out.println(dtSource);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-02-03T23:22:23.000Z
```